# I am trying scrapy crawling spider using the general spider template with selenium , but when crawling to the product details page it give wrong data

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, scrapy-selenium

> Blockquote

I am trying to extract the href link and then i joined the url and then i give the seleniumRequest with the joined url
my code works and it crawls the data but at the result it produce the same repetative data
the data that are crawled will be repetative

it look like everything is fine and no error but the output is repetative and data are also coming from different product link

```
############# STACK OVERFLOW PLAESE HELP I'm AN BEGGINER IN SCRAPY WITH SELENIUM ###########
############# I THINK SOMETHING WITH MY PRODUCT PRICE URL #############
############# SOMETHING WRONG WITH URL #############################
#########This is my code

import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

class AmazonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Amazon'


    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='https://www.amazon.com',
            wait_time=3,
            screenshot=True,
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = response.meta['driver']
        search_input = 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")
        search_input.send_keys('smartphones')
        search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        html = driver.page_source
        response_obj = Selector(text=html)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

        links = response_obj.xpath("//h2[@class='a-size-mini a-spacing-none a-color-base s-line-clamp-2']/a")
        for link in links:

            product_link = link.xpath(".//@href").get()

            absolute_url = response.urljoin(product_link)

            yield SeleniumRequest(url=absolute_url, wait_time=8, callback=self.parse_price, 
                                                        dont_filter=True )

     def parse_price(self, response):

        driver = response.meta['driver']
        htmlbody = driver.page_source

        response_object = Selector(text=htmlbody)

        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

        sleep(5)
        name = response_object.xpath("//h1[@class='a-size-large a-spacing-none']/span").get()

        yield {
            'name': name
        }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you get in `absolute_url` - maybe it need something more. And check what you have in `reponse.url`. You use `don_fitler=True` so it may load the same url many times (if you use it in `Request`). You should also check in web browser how it work. Maybe it doesn't use request `GET` but `POST` and you would have to rather `click` link in `selenium`. Shortly: you have to debug data.

Comment: if you work with `driver.page_source` then there is no sense to use `driver.set_window_size(..)` - it is useless. it can't change HTML which you already have as string.

Comment: do you test it without `headless` to see browser? It seems all requests use the same window/tab and because code runs fast so browser has no time to load new url - and you get always the same HTML. You have to `sleep` before you get `driver.page_source`. But even this sometimes may not work.

Comment: @furas thanks for your help.I hope your suggestions helps me to solve the problem.yes it is something problem with the response url.I am trying to debug.